# Jquery Dropdown Filter : Uncaught TypeError: "#ID".val is not a function

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I'm working on a code where I'm merging the selections from the previous select questions to filter and populate my dependent dropdown.

However, I'm stuck at a point in the code which I'm using to filter by concatenating the values of the previous question selections with a "."(dot) in between.

The code:

```
$('#SelectPhone option')
    .hide()
    .filter([value=('#PhoneType').val() + '.' + ('#AllPhoneFeature').val()])
    .show();
    $("#SelectPhone").val([]);
```

The Console error: Uncaught TypeError: ***"#PhoneType".val is not a function***

Please help, I'm unable to move forward and have tried multiple changes to no avail.

Find the link to entire JS Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/rk6gxu3d/

Comment: Typo.  You're missing the quotes around your filter selector.  You are giving it a malformed array as it currently is.

Comment: Loads of typos.. You are also missing the $ on front of .filter([value=HERE('#PhoneType').val() + '.' + HERE('#AllPhoneFeature').val()])

Comment: `[value=('#PhoneType').val()` tons of typos on that one line

Comment: Hi @epascarello ! Tried all your suggestions. Tried putting quotes around the filter selector too. I'm a noob at coding and am unable to crack this one for some reason. Would be most grateful if someone could help me get this working. jsfiddle.net/mithunu/fs86q9no/2